# Designing a mini search engine and data structures

Tags: search, data-structures, disk

I designed a mini search engine in which I am provided with a bunch of files. What I did is that I crawled these files and I formed a hash table with the key being the hashed value of the word and the table entry is a binary tree which holds all the words with the same hash and some other information related to the word.

I understand that this datastructure exists in the memory. I am thinking of scaling the problem. If I was provided with a huge number of entries, the memory will not be able to hold this huge amount of data so I will have to store it persistently on a hard drive. However, as far as I know, data is stored in hard disks as blocks and I, as a programmer, have no control over how the data is stored on disk. So how can I enforce the data to be stored on the disk the same way they were stored in the memory.

In simple words, I understand Data structures are important for processing data in an efficient manner (if the right data structure is used), but a programmer controls only the data structure of the data in memory. If the data is large, how can a programmer store data in a disk for efficient retrieval?

Answer (score 0):

Usually for doing mapping between word and documents that contains that word inverted index is used as a data structure.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index